# How to download a file using a button on a ribbon on a Model Driven App with C# Plugins?

Tags: c#, file, plugins, download, dataverse

I managed to integrate code that allows me to download a file from a Dataverse table within a plugin and I can perform automation tasks on this document

```cs
private static byte[] DownloadFile(IOrganizationService orgService, string entityName, Guid recordGuid, string fileAttributeName)
{
    var initializeFileBlocksDownloadRequest = new InitializeFileBlocksDownloadRequest
    {
        Target = new EntityReference(entityName, recordGuid), FileAttributeName = fileAttributeName
    };

    var initializeFileBlocksDownloadResponse = (InitializeFileBlocksDownloadResponse)orgService.Execute(initializeFileBlocksDownloadRequest);

    DownloadBlockRequest downloadBlockRequest = new DownloadBlockRequest
    {
        FileContinuationToken = initializeFileBlocksDownloadResponse.FileContinuationToken
    };

    var downloadBlockResponse = (DownloadBlockResponse)orgService.Execute(downloadBlockRequest);
            
    return downloadBlockResponse.Data;
}
```

But after I've completed my automation task I wish to download this file to the local download directory of the person who triggered the plugin, from what I know you can use **File.WriteAllBytes(<File_Name>, downloadBlockResponse.Data);** but its not working, is there any workaround or direct methods of downloading a file using a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Plugin code is running on the server side. The server has no access to a user's local storage. If it would have access, this would be a major security issue.

However, the `InitializeFileBlocksDownloadRequest` and `DownloadBlockRequest` can actually be invoked from JavaScript. Write a script that uses these requests to get the data and that can be invoked form a ribbon button.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm very new to Plugins in general so I don't know how to specifically execute this... I want to perform operations inside the plugin on the document itself.. which is working, I want the RESULTING file to be downloaded on the user's local system, how do I manage this?